# Return "NOT NULL" in a ternary where I need to say == NOT NULL?

Tags: c#, lambda, entity-framework-4

Given this code:

```
            dataSource = this.db.DailyProductionReportSummaries.Where(
                x => x.ShiftDate >= start && x.ShiftDate <= end &&
                x.Shift == (shift != null ? shift.Code : "SOMETHING ELSE") &&  //TODO: "SOMETHING ELSE" where it's not null
                x.LineNumber == (shift != null ? lineNumber : 0) && //TODO: 0 where it's not null
                x.ProductCode == (productNumber != 0 ? productNumber.ToString() : "SOMETHING ELSE") //TODO: "SOMETHING ELSE" where it's not null
                ).ToList();
```

I need to say in each of those ternaries marked with "TODO" something like (targeting specifically the first line with `//TODO`:

> If `shift` has something in it, return shift.Code otherwise, return "Something" that will evaluate to `x.Shift == NOT NULL` (or more clearly that it evaluates to `x.shift != null`)

Am I just holding on to a wish here or do I need to go ahead and expand that into a bunch of `if` statements? (I'm trying to condense multiple if statements into something more compact and adaptable to changing configurations without lots of logic changes or rewrites...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most readable alternative *is* to expand that into a bunch of `if` statements. Keep in mind that you do not need to spell out each alternative, you do not need a bunch of `if` nesting, you can simply chain filters by calling `Where` repeatedly.

```
var query = this.db.DailyProductionReportSummaries.AsQueryable();

query = query.Where(x => x.ShiftDate >= start && x.ShiftDate <= end);

if (shift == null)
    query = query.Where(x => x.Shift != null
                          && x.LineNumber != null);
else
    query = query.Where(x => x.Shift == shift.Code
                          && x.LineNumber == lineNumber);

if (productNumber == 0)
    query = query.Where(x => x.ProductCode != null);
else
    query = query.Where(x => x.ProductCode == productNumber.ToString());

dataSource = query.ToList();
```

Comment: Holy crap! I knew you chain but not like that. This is absolutely incredible! Imma try this out and let you know how it works!

Comment: @MetalPhoenix Remember that IQueryable's represent "a query to do", not the result of such. Assuming the [semantically] equivalent end operation/tree how the IQueryable is made is largely irrelevant (with all the restrictions of queryables that EF can use, etc). View the actual SQL of the applied queryable (ie. at the ToList) to see what is finally happening.

Comment: Yeah, this seems to be more of what I need with a slight logic modification...much easier to deal with productNumber if we always assume that it has a value (which it will). This is a better solution overall than what I was trying to accomplish! It's easy to forget that it's not the actual result or action but rather "to do" since it's separated by EF. Thanks for the reminder.